# How to change the about:config shortcut in unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, shortcuts

how can i change it to [Gunity](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/go/1/http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/gunity-app-lets-you-tweak-the-unity-desktop/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, it's hardcoded in Unity. See [the source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity-place-applications/trunk/view/head:/src/runner.vala) (scroll to the bottom).

But it's just as quick to press the Super key to bring up the dash, and then type *Gunity*.